# Parsing with Jsoup in arraylist

Tags: android, xml, html-parsing, jsoup

How could I parse this with jsoup?

```
    <!-- NOVINEEE -->
<div class="right_naslov"><a href="/e-novine">e-novine</a></div>

  <div class="right_post">
    <span class="right_post_nadnaslov"><font class="nadnaslov">Zanimljiv zadatak</font></span><span class="right_post_datum"><font class="datum">12.12.2014.</font></span>
    <span class="right_post_naslov_v"><font class="naslov"><a href="/e-novine/n/?id=340">Profesor učenicima zadao najbolji zadatak ikad!</a></font></span>
    <span class="right_post_podnaslov"><font class="podnaslov"></font></span>
    <div class="right_post_tekst"><a href="/e-novine/n/?id=340"><img width="180" align="left" class="novine_slika_thumbm" border="0" src="/fajlovi/slike/thumbm/4161-zadatak_naslovna.jpg" /></a><p>72-godi&scaron;nji profesor biv&scaron;im učenicima iz godine u godinu &scaron;alje pisma &scaron;to nije lak zadatak jer mnogi ne žive u istoj državi. Iako radi ne&scaron;to stvarno posebno, Bruce sebe i dalje smatra prosječnim profesorom. Učenici ipak smatraju suprotno...</p>
<div>&nbsp;</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to get the content of right_naslov, and inside the font class of nadnaslov, naslov, and the img src and the a href of right_post_tekst.

I tried doing something like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements post = doc.select("right_naslov right_post nadnaslov");
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put("rank", post.text());
            // Get the second td
            map.put("country", post.text());
            // Get the third td
            map.put("population", post.text());

            // Set all extracted Jsoup Elements into the array
            arraylist.add(map);
```

And afterwards I do:

```
resultp = data.get(position);

// Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
rank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank);
country = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);
population = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.population);


// Capture position and set results to the TextViews
rank.setText(resultp.get(PocetnaFragment.RANK));
country.setText(resultp.get(PocetnaFragment.COUNTRY));
population.setText(resultp.get(PocetnaFragment.POPULATION));
```

I've been following this tutorial: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-jsoup-listview-images-texts-html-tables-tutorial/

**There are multiple `right_posts`**

Thanks

---

**UPDATE**

Getting the following error after the answer that is located down (after all the comments):

```
02-14 23:50:17.490    2469-2530/gimbi.edu.ba W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.jsoup.select.Elements org.jsoup.nodes.Element.select(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
02-14 23:50:17.494    2469-2530/gimbi.edu.ba W/System.err﹕ at gimbi.edu.ba.PocetnaFragment$JsoupListView.doInBackground(PocetnaFragment.java:147)
02-14 23:50:17.494    2469-2530/gimbi.edu.ba W/System.err﹕ at gimbi.edu.ba.PocetnaFragment$JsoupListView.doInBackground(PocetnaFragment.java:103)
02-14 23:50:17.494    2469-2530/gimbi.edu.ba W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-14 23:50:17.494    2469-2530/gimbi.edu.ba W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-14 23:50:17.494    2469-2530/gimbi.edu.ba W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-14 23:50:17.494    2469-2530/gimbi.edu.ba W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-14 23:50:17.494    2469-2530/gimbi.edu.ba W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-14 23:50:17.494    2469-2530/gimbi.edu.ba W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-14 23:50:46.713    2469-4859/gimbi.edu.ba W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.jsoup.select.Elements org.jsoup.nodes.Element.select(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
02-14 23:50:46.718    2469-4859/gimbi.edu.ba W/System.err﹕ at gimbi.edu.ba.PocetnaFragment$JsoupListView.doInBackground(PocetnaFragment.java:147)
02-14 23:50:46.718    2469-4859/gimbi.edu.ba W/System.err﹕ at gimbi.edu.ba.PocetnaFragment$JsoupListView.doInBackground(PocetnaFragment.java:103)
02-14 23:50:46.719    2469-4859/gimbi.edu.ba W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-14 23:50:46.719    2469-4859/gimbi.edu.ba W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-14 23:50:46.719    2469-4859/gimbi.edu.ba W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-14 23:50:46.719    2469-4859/gimbi.edu.ba W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-14 23:50:46.719    2469-4859/gimbi.edu.ba W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-14 23:50:46.719    2469-4859/gimbi.edu.ba W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

As I said down there, I tried deleting the `img element`, but it's same for all elements when I call `map.put` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a read on this [link](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) regarding how Jsoup is used to extract data.

Following is my example according to your scenario.

```
    Document doc = null;
    Element aEle = null;
    Element fontEle = null;

    try {
        doc = ......

        /** Get A tag that is under DIV with classname right_naslov **/
        aEle = doc.select("div.right_naslov > a").first();
        if (aEle != null) {
            System.out.println("right_naslov content: " + aEle.ownText());
        }

        /** Get Font tag with [classname=nadnaslov] under span[classname=right_post_nadnaslov] under div[lassname=right_post]  **/
        /** Try to get Font[classname=naslov] with the following method **/
        fontEle = doc.select("div.right_post > span.right_post_nadnaslov > font.nadnaslov").first();
        if (fontEle != null) {
            System.out.println("font nadnaslov content: " + fontEle.ownText());
        }

        /** Get A tag that is under div[classname=right_post_tekst] under div[classname=right_post] **/
        aEle = doc.select("div.right_post > div.right_post_tekst > a").first();
        if (aEle != null) {
            System.out.println("a href: " + aEle.attr("href"));

            /** Get inner IMG tag with classname as 'novine_slika_thumbm' **/
            Element imgEle = aEle.select("img.novine_slika_thumbm").first();
            if (imgEle != null) {
                System.out.println("img src: " + imgEle.attr("src"));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Above example will only works if there is only one `DIV[classname=right_naslov]` or `DIV[classname=right_post]` in the HTML document that you are parsing as I use `Elements.first()` in extracting data, which means I always select the first Element that meets our extract criteria. Try to play around with Jsoup, have fun. Once you get the all the data, then store them in either `Hashmap` or `ArrayList` as you like.

---

**Updated**

What you could do is select multiple DIVs[classname=right_post] with `Document.select()` which returns you `Elements` object. Then loop each `Element` to get its inner data. In my following example, you will get have two `HashMap` items in `arraylist` variable.

There are **2** div[classname=right_naslov] and I only retrieve the second one which after `<!-- NOVINEEE -->` comment section. There are **5** div[classname=right_post] and I already ignored those that are without inner element span[classname=right_post_nadnaslov].

```
    List<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    Elements aEles = null;
    Elements divRightPostEles = null;
    String rightNaslov = null;
    Document doc = null;

    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        /** Get A tag that is under DIV with classname right_naslov **/
        aEles = doc.select("div.right_naslov > a");
        if (aEles != null && aEles.size() > 0) {
            if (aEles.size() == 2)
                rightNaslov = aEles.get(1).ownText();
            else
                rightNaslov = aEles.first().ownText();
        }

        /**
         * Since you say there are multiple DIV with right_post as
         * classname, we will get all those right post elements and loop
         * them one by one to retrieve its inner elements
         **/
        divRightPostEles = doc.select("div.right_post");

        for (Element rightPostDiv : divRightPostEles) {
            /** Each loop of this represents a right_post DIV element **/

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            /**
             * Get Font tag with [classname=nadnaslov] under
             * span[classname=right_post_nadnaslov] under
             * div[lassname=right_post]
             **/
            /** Try to get Font[classname=naslov] with the following method **/
            Elements fontNadnaslov = rightPostDiv
                    .select("span.right_post_nadnaslov > font.nadnaslov");

            /**
             * Get A tag that is under div[classname=right_post_tekst] under
             * div[classname=right_post]
             **/
            Element aRightPostTekst = rightPostDiv.select(
                    "div.right_post_tekst > a[href]").first();

            // Retrive Jsoup Elements
            if (fontNadnaslov != null && fontNadnaslov.size() > 0) {
                map.put("country", fontNadnaslov.first().ownText());

                if (aRightPostTekst != null) {
                    map.put("population", aRightPostTekst.attr("href"));

                    Element img = aRightPostTekst.select("img[src]").first();

                    if (img != null)
                        map.put("image", img.attr("src"));
                }

                if (rightNaslov != null)
                    map.put("rank", rightNaslov);
                // Set all extracted Jsoup Elements into the array
                arraylist.add(map);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: There is multiple divs of classname right post. I tried wrapping it in a for function, it returns as two seperate list view items, but it get's all of the possible right_post_nadnaslov, and only one a href (aEle). How could I make them appear seperate? Here's what I tried to do: http://pastebin.com/ZZse378K

Comment: I replaced that `input and doc.output because` I couldn't import anything, I replaced it with `Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();` And I'm getting the following error: http://pastebin.com/6DH8iCxV, and it references me to ListViewAdapter (following lines):     `@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }` ,here's my ListViewAdapter.java: http://pastebin.com/cZtsrDpL

Comment: I'm not really good in Android but I would try to help out. Initialize data in ListViewAdapter with a value. ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data = null; or ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

Comment: I used `arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();` instead of `List<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();`, also removed those  `system.out.println`'s (deleted the last for function), I don't get any errors, but it's blank, like it doesn't return any data.

Comment: Getting the following warning(s): http://pastebin.com/aicUBvYJ, I tried deleting the `img` element, but it's same for every element in `map.put`

Comment: Which URL are you parsing from? I will try that out at my side.

Comment: I had updated my answer. There are two div with classname as 'right_naslov', so I take the second element as you mentioned that you want 'NOVINEEE'.

Comment: It all works great if I change `List<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();` to `arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();`, but how I think you misplaced the `map.put(img, ...)`, and it seems I couldn't get the image. Thanks

Comment: Do you need the image?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70962/discussion-between-core-m-and-wilts-c).